# Remove duplicates from a column SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct

I'm pretty new to SQL and I want to remove distinct elements from a query in SQL.

I have this query:

```
SELECT 
    LabelingTasks.SessionID, LabelingFiles.LabelingFileID, 
    LabelingFiles.Link, LabelingTasks.TaskTypeID,
    LabelingTasks.StartFrame, LabelingTasks.EndFrame,
    LabelingTasks.DataMarkingTypeID 
FROM
    LabelingTasks 
INNER JOIN 
    LabelingFiles ON LabelingTaskID = LabelingFiles.LabelingTaskID 
WHERE 
    LabelingTasks.MovieID = 10832 
    AND LabelingTasks.DataMarkingTypeID = 5 
    AND LabelingTasks.TaskTypeID = 4 
GROUP BY 
    StartFrame 
ORDER BY 
    StartFrame ASC
```

The output looks like this:

```
Header1 Header2 Header3 Header4 StartFrame EndFrame Header7
-----------------------------------------------------------
 xxx      xxx    xxx     xxx     0          3000     xxx
 xxx      xxx    xxx     xxx    3001        6000     xxx
 xxx      xxx    xxx     xxx    3001        6000     xxx
 xxx      xxx    xxx     xxx    6001        9000     xxx
```

The desired output should look like this:

```
   Header1 Header2 Header3 Header4 StartFrame EndFrame Header7
   -----------------------------------------------------------
     xxx      xxx    xxx     xxx     0          3000     xxx
     xxx      xxx    xxx     xxx    3001        6000     xxx
     xxx      xxx    xxx     xxx    6001        9000     xxx
```

Comment: Please replace the `xxx` with their actual values.

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT` *would* only return 3 rows for the above, because all your other columns have the value `'xxx'`. The fact that you have obscured your data means that it isn't representative of the problem.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, these headers are irelevant :)

Comment: @jack Tim is referring to your obfuscated data; as presented, `select distinct` is the answer to your question.

Comment: For `StartFrame` of `3001` you have two distinct rows. Which of the two would you want to keep? Would `SELECT max(header1), max(header2), max(header3), max(header4), startframe, endframe, max(header7) FROM ... GROUP BY startframe, endframe;` do the trick?

Comment: @JNevill, i want to keep the last change in DB

Comment: @jack How would you discern the last change from this table? Is there a timestamp/date column that tracks when a record was added? If so, can you update your question to reflect that. Your query to identify which record should be removed would look something like `SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY startframe, endframe ORDER BY your_date_or_timestamp_column DESC) as rn FROM <your from statement>;`. Now anything with an `rn>1` is a duplicate to be deleted (as an example).

Answer (score 1):

I assume that 'xxx' in the sample dataset means any value that is not important for the question at hand but column must form the part of output. Also, assuming that pair of StartFrame and EndFrame values are only important.
What you want really want in output are list of rows having distinct StartFrame-EndFrame values.
The SQL below will produce the desired result, provided that the LabelingTasks.LabelingTaskID unique identifier for all values of StartFrame-EndFrame values.

```
SELECT 
    LabelingTasks.SessionID, LabelingFiles.LabelingFileID, 
    LabelingFiles.Link, LabelingTasks.TaskTypeID,
    LabelingTasks.StartFrame, LabelingTasks.EndFrame,
    LabelingTasks.DataMarkingTypeID 
FROM
    LabelingTasks 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT LabelingTasks.StartFrame, LabelingTasks.EndFrame,
           MIN(LabelingTasks.LabelingTaskID) AS UID
    FROM LabelingTasks 
    GROUP BY LabelingTasks.StartFrame, LabelingTasks.EndFrame
) U ON U.UID = LabelingTasks.LabelingTaskID
INNER JOIN 
    LabelingFiles ON LabelingTaskID = LabelingFiles.LabelingTaskID 
WHERE 
    LabelingTasks.MovieID = 10832 
    AND LabelingTasks.DataMarkingTypeID = 5 
    AND LabelingTasks.TaskTypeID = 4 
GROUP BY 
    StartFrame 
ORDER BY 
    StartFrame ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check, where row 2 and 3 is not unique (I think the SessionID is the problem). If every other entry in each column is unique, your current statement will work, because the distinct-statement will filter out all duplicates.

Answer (score -1):

Please try this

```
SELECT DISTINCT(LabelingTasks.StartFrame, LabelingTasks.EndFrame),  LabelingTasks.SessionID,LabelingFiles.LabelingFileID, LabelingFiles.Link, LabelingTasks.TaskTypeID ,LabelingTasks.DataMarkingTypeID 
FROM LabelingTasks 
INNER JOIN LabelingFiles ON LabelingTasks.LabelingTaskID=LabelingFiles.LabelingTaskID 
WHERE LabelingTasks.MovieID=10832 AND LabelingTasks.DataMarkingTypeID=5 AND LabelingTasks.TaskTypeID=4 GROUP BY StartFrame ORDER BY StartFrame ASC
```

Let me know if it doesn't works

Comment: `DISTINCT()` isn't a function. It applies against all columns in the query.

Comment: Column 'LabelingTasks.SessionID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.